# How to subtract the pixel mean

Tags: python, numpy

The mean_pixel is: `103.939, 116.779, 123.68`

This is how I am loading the image.

```
image = Image.open(image_name)
image = image.convert('RGB')
```

I've been trying to use Numpy to subtract the mean pixel, but I can't seem to convert the image back to an image from an array.

This is how I am converting to RGB and BGR:

```
def rgb2bgr(image):
    data = np.array(image)
    red, green, blue = data.T 
    data = np.array([blue, green, red])
    data = data.transpose()
    image = Image.fromarray(data)
    return image

def bgr2rgb(image):
    data = np.array(image)
    blue, green, red = data.T
    data = np.array([red, green, blue])
    data = data.transpose()
    image = Image.fromarray(data)
    return image
```

I am trying to replicate this Lua processing code: https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style/blob/master/neural_style.lua#L416-L437, for Pytorch.

How do I properly subtract the mean pixel from my image?

Edit:

This doesn't seem to work correctly because the resulting image is completely messed up:

```
def SubtractMean(image):
    data = np.array(image)
    mean_pixel = np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939]).reshape((1,1,3))
    data = data - mean_pixel
    image = Image.fromarray((data), 'RGB')
    return image
```

Maybe I can subtract the mean after I convert the image into a tensor?

```
loader = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((image_size)), transforms.ToTensor()])  # resize and convert to tensor
image = loader(image)
mean_pixel = torch.FloatTensor([123.68, 116.779, 103.939])
mean_pixel = mean_pixel.view(3, 1, 1).expand_as(image)
image.add(-mean_pixel)
```

Comment: What is `blue, green, red = data.T; data = np.array([red, green, blue]); data = data.transpose()` all about? It seems to do nothing...

Comment: Also, what is the question: how to subtract 3 values from a (ny, nx, 3) array (because you ask at the end: _"How do I properly subtract the mean pixel from my image"_) or how to convert it to an `Image` (since you say: _"...I can't seem to convert the image back to an image from an array"_)?

Comment: You might need to convert the image array back to uint8 after you've done the subtraction, but it's hard to tell since you've not included the exception or what went wrong. Please try to include an MCVE next time.

Comment: @AGNGazer that's changing the colorspace from RGB, to BGR.

Comment: My question is how to subtract the mean pixel value from the "image" variable. My attempts with haven't been working thus far.

Comment: Why did you say _This doesn't seem to work correctly because the resulting image is completely messed up"_? Specifically, why do you say that the image is "messed up" or even better, what would be a "correct" result?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that the results appear "messed-up" to you because of conversion of the negative numbers to positive `numpy.uint8`. I am not familiar with "Lua processing code" that you mention and so I do not know what is expected. However, you are subtracting "mean" correctly.